# Outlook VSTO add-in showing wrong preview in Mail

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, appointment

I am working on a VSTO Outlook add-in project. The problem I am having is: appointments created using the add-in show wrong preview on Mail screen.

[image: Preview shows font details instead of the body]

The problem happens only when I change the view (Change View on top left corner in the attached image then select "Preview"). I am not sure what I am missing. Other invites that are not generated by my add-in show properly.

Here is how I create my appointment:

```
newAppointment.RTFBody = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(BuildBody());
newAppointment.MeetingStatus = OlMeetingStatus.olMeeting;
newAppointment.Location = "My Location";
newAppointment.Display(false);
```

Comment: Most likely your RTF is invalid.
Are you sure the RTF body is right? Take a look at the appointment with OutlookSpy (click IMessage) and check the PR_BODY and PR)RTF_COMPRESSED properties.

Comment: That could be it since I am modifying the content dynamically without using any RTF parser.Is there any RTF parser you'd recommend for VSTO programming as there does not seem to be a native one. The only operation I want to do really is: merge what the user has entered (existing body) with some formatted new text (auto-generated). So far, I've been splitting and replacing one part with a new one or inserting the new part in the old one by replacing a pre-defined text (e.g. "USER-BODY-TAG-REPLACE-HERE").

Comment: Try to save your RTF in a file and open it in WordPad. So have you tried to look at the appointment in OutlookSpy?

Comment: @Hochman7G to refer to the mailobject from formregion, use `this.OutlookItem`